# Set the Dropdown list value as per the input field

Tags: javascript, html

I am new to javascript. I am pushing the dropdown list value into the input fields. I'm doing that successfully. When I try to enter a value into the input field that already exists in the dropdown list the function call shows correct values. The dapartment label dropdown changes but subcatagory div dropdown list value doesn't change until I click in that div. How can change that?
Any help would be much appreciated

```js
function fields() {
    var seldprt = document.getElementById("seldprt");
    var section = seldprt.value;
    var dprt_input = section;
    var input_Department = document.getElementById("departmentinput");
    input_Department.value = dprt_input;  
  
    if (section == "Finance") {
        document.getElementById("FinanceDiv").style.display = "";
        document.getElementById("SalesDiv").style.display = "none";
        document.getElementById("ITDiv").style.display = "none";
        var subsection = document.getElementById("FinanceDiv_subcatagory");
        var input_Subcatagory = document.getElementById("subcatagoryinput");
        input_Subcatagory.value = sub_catagory_input;
    } else if (section == "Sales") { 
        document.getElementById("SalesDiv").style.display = "";
        document.getElementById("FinanceDiv").style.display = "none";
        document.getElementById("ITDiv").style.display = "none";
        var subsection = document.getElementById("SalesDiv_subcatagory");
        var sub_catagory_input = subsection.value;
        var input_Subcatagory = document.getElementById("subcatagoryinput");
        input_Subcatagory.value=sub_catagory_input;
    
    } else if (section == "IT") { 
        document.getElementById("ITDiv").style.display = "";
        document.getElementById("SalesDiv").style.display = "none";
        document.getElementById("FinanceDiv").style.display = "none";
        var subsection = document.getElementById("ITDiv_subcatagory");
        var sub_catagory_input = subsection.value;
        var input_Subcatagory = document.getElementById("subcatagoryinput");
        input_Subcatagory.value=sub_catagory_input;  
    }    
}

function previous_values() {
    var input_Department = document.getElementById("departmentinput").value;
    var input_Subcatagory = document.getElementById("subcatagoryinput").value;
    alert(input_Department+","+input_Subcatagory);
    //seldprt.value = input_Department; 
    if(input_Department != null) {   
        alert();
        var seldprt = document.getElementById("seldprt");
        seldprt.value = input_Department; 
        var Finance_subsection = document.getElementById("FinanceDiv_subcatagory");
        var Sales_subsection = document.getElementById("SalesDiv_subcatagory");
        var ITDiv_subsection = document.getElementById("ITDiv_subcatagory");
        if (input_Department == "Finance") {
            document.getElementById("FinanceDiv_subcatagory").value = input_Subcatagory;
            //Finance_subsection.value = input_Subcatagory;
            //alert(Finance_subsection+"Finance_subsection");  
        }
        if (input_Department == "Sales") {
            document.getElementById("SalesDiv_subcatagory").value = input_Subcatagory; 
            //alert(Sales_subsection.value+"subsection value");
        } 
        if(input_Department=="IT") {
            document.getElementById("ITDiv_subcatagory").value = input_Subcatagory;
            //alert(ITDiv_subsection+"subsection value");
        }
        //alert("if block"+seldprt.value+","+Finance_subsection.value+","+Sales_subsection.value+","+ITDiv_subsection.value);
         
    } /* else {
        var seldprt = document.getElementById("seldprt");
        seldprt.value = input_Department;
        alert("else block"+seldprt.value);
        var Finance_subsection = document.getElementById("FinanceDiv_subcatagory");
        Finance_subsection.value = input_Department;
        var Sales_subsection = document.getElementById("SalesDiv_subcatagory");
        Sales_subsection.value = input_Department;  
        var ITDiv_subsection = document.getElementById("ITDiv_subcatagory");
        ITDiv_subsection.value = input_Department;
        alert("else block");
   
    } */
}
```

```html
<body onload="preparePage();fields();previous_values();" >
 <div class="title"><%=getUserName(request)%>'s Emergency Contact</div><hr/>
 <div class="instructions">Please provide the name and telephone number of a person that we may contact in case of an emergency.</div>
<div class="container" onclick="fields()">
<div onchange = "" class="departmentdiv">
  <label>Department:</label> 
  <div align="right" class="selectdiv">
  <select id = "seldprt">
   <option value = "Finance">Finance</option>
   <option value = "Sales">Sales</option>
   <option value = "IT">IT</option>   
  </select>
  </div>
 </div>

 
  
 <div id="FinanceDiv" onclick="" class="subcatagorydiv" >
  <label>Section Name:</label>
  <div align="right" class="selectdiv">
  <select id = "FinanceDiv_subcatagory">
   <option value = "Reimbursment">Reimbursment</option>
   <option value = "Billing">Billing</option>
   <option value = "Salaries">Salaries</option>
  </select>
  </div>
 
</div>
<div id="SalesDiv" onclick="previous_values()" class="subcatagorydiv" style="display:none;">
  <label>Section Name:</label>
  <div align="right" class="selectdiv">
  <select id = "SalesDiv_subcatagory">
   <option value = "Total Sales">Total Sales</option>
   <option value = "Purchases">Purchases</option>
   <option value = "BestProduct">BestProduct</option>
  </select>
  </div>
</div>

<div id="ITDiv" onclick="previous_values()" class="subcatagorydiv" style="display:none;" >
  <label>Section Name:</label>
  <div align="right" class="selectdiv">
  <select id = "ITDiv_subcatagory">
   <option value = "Internee">Internee</option>
   <option value = "Associates">Associates</option>
   <option value = "Managers">Managers</option>
  </select>
  </div>
</div>
</div>


  <form action="" method="post" >
   <div class="entry" onclick="previous_values()">Name</div>
   <input type="text" name="name" id="departmentinput">
   <div class="entry" onchange="previous_values()">Telephone Number</div>
   <input type="text" name="telephone" id="subcatagoryinput">
   <div id="readwrite_buttons" class="hide">
    <button id="ok" onclick="document.forms[0].submit();return false;">OK</button>
    <button id="cancel" onclick="javascript:window.close();return false;">Cancel</button>
   </div>
   <div id="readonly_buttons" class="hide">
    <button id="back" onclick="javascript:window.close();return false;">Back</button>
   </div>
  </form>
 </body>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to hook up the `onchange` event on the `<select>` element (seldprt) to call `fields()`.  Also - `onchange` events don't apply to `div` elements.

This works because you have written `fields()` to read the new value, and re-render the DOM.  I honestly didn't read the rest of the code.

You probably have written too much code for your purposes, but that's ok because you're still learning.  I would recommend rewriting with minimal functionality, verifying each piece works, and then adding more features a little at a time.

See fixed snippet:

```js
function fields() {
    var seldprt = document.getElementById("seldprt");
    var section = seldprt.value;
    var dprt_input = section;
    var input_Department = document.getElementById("departmentinput");
    input_Department.value = dprt_input;  
  
    if (section == "Finance") {
        document.getElementById("FinanceDiv").style.display = "";
        document.getElementById("SalesDiv").style.display = "none";
        document.getElementById("ITDiv").style.display = "none";
        var subsection = document.getElementById("FinanceDiv_subcatagory");
        var input_Subcatagory = document.getElementById("subcatagoryinput");
        input_Subcatagory.value = sub_catagory_input;
    } else if (section == "Sales") { 
        document.getElementById("SalesDiv").style.display = "";
        document.getElementById("FinanceDiv").style.display = "none";
        document.getElementById("ITDiv").style.display = "none";
        var subsection = document.getElementById("SalesDiv_subcatagory");
        var sub_catagory_input = subsection.value;
        var input_Subcatagory = document.getElementById("subcatagoryinput");
        input_Subcatagory.value=sub_catagory_input;
    
    } else if (section == "IT") { 
        document.getElementById("ITDiv").style.display = "";
        document.getElementById("SalesDiv").style.display = "none";
        document.getElementById("FinanceDiv").style.display = "none";
        var subsection = document.getElementById("ITDiv_subcatagory");
        var sub_catagory_input = subsection.value;
        var input_Subcatagory = document.getElementById("subcatagoryinput");
        input_Subcatagory.value=sub_catagory_input;  
    }    
}

function previous_values() {
    var input_Department = document.getElementById("departmentinput").value;
    var input_Subcatagory = document.getElementById("subcatagoryinput").value;
    alert(input_Department+","+input_Subcatagory);
    //seldprt.value = input_Department; 
    if(input_Department != null) {   
        alert();
        var seldprt = document.getElementById("seldprt");
        seldprt.value = input_Department; 
        var Finance_subsection = document.getElementById("FinanceDiv_subcatagory");
        var Sales_subsection = document.getElementById("SalesDiv_subcatagory");
        var ITDiv_subsection = document.getElementById("ITDiv_subcatagory");
        if (input_Department == "Finance") {
            document.getElementById("FinanceDiv_subcatagory").value = input_Subcatagory;
            //Finance_subsection.value = input_Subcatagory;
            //alert(Finance_subsection+"Finance_subsection");  
        }
        if (input_Department == "Sales") {
            document.getElementById("SalesDiv_subcatagory").value = input_Subcatagory; 
            //alert(Sales_subsection.value+"subsection value");
        } 
        if(input_Department=="IT") {
            document.getElementById("ITDiv_subcatagory").value = input_Subcatagory;
            //alert(ITDiv_subsection+"subsection value");
        }
        //alert("if block"+seldprt.value+","+Finance_subsection.value+","+Sales_subsection.value+","+ITDiv_subsection.value);
         
    } /* else {
        var seldprt = document.getElementById("seldprt");
        seldprt.value = input_Department;
        alert("else block"+seldprt.value);
        var Finance_subsection = document.getElementById("FinanceDiv_subcatagory");
        Finance_subsection.value = input_Department;
        var Sales_subsection = document.getElementById("SalesDiv_subcatagory");
        Sales_subsection.value = input_Department;  
        var ITDiv_subsection = document.getElementById("ITDiv_subcatagory");
        ITDiv_subsection.value = input_Department;
        alert("else block");
   
    } */
}
```

```html
<body onload="preparePage();fields();previous_values();" >
 <div class="title"><%=getUserName(request)%>'s Emergency Contact</div><hr/>
 <div class="instructions">Please provide the name and telephone number of a person that we may contact in case of an emergency.</div>
<div class="container" onclick="fields()">
<div class="departmentdiv">
  <label>Department:</label> 
  <div align="right" class="selectdiv">
  <select onchange = "fields()" id = "seldprt">
   <option value = "Finance">Finance</option>
   <option value = "Sales">Sales</option>
   <option value = "IT">IT</option>   
  </select>
  </div>
 </div>

 
  
 <div id="FinanceDiv" onclick="" class="subcatagorydiv" >
  <label>Section Name:</label>
  <div align="right" class="selectdiv">
  <select id = "FinanceDiv_subcatagory">
   <option value = "Reimbursment">Reimbursment</option>
   <option value = "Billing">Billing</option>
   <option value = "Salaries">Salaries</option>
  </select>
  </div>
 
</div>
<div id="SalesDiv" onclick="previous_values()" class="subcatagorydiv" style="display:none;">
  <label>Section Name:</label>
  <div align="right" class="selectdiv">
  <select id = "SalesDiv_subcatagory">
   <option value = "Total Sales">Total Sales</option>
   <option value = "Purchases">Purchases</option>
   <option value = "BestProduct">BestProduct</option>
  </select>
  </div>
</div>

<div id="ITDiv" onclick="previous_values()" class="subcatagorydiv" style="display:none;" >
  <label>Section Name:</label>
  <div align="right" class="selectdiv">
  <select id = "ITDiv_subcatagory">
   <option value = "Internee">Internee</option>
   <option value = "Associates">Associates</option>
   <option value = "Managers">Managers</option>
  </select>
  </div>
</div>
</div>


  <form action="" method="post" >
   <div class="entry" onclick="previous_values()">Name</div>
   <input type="text" name="name" id="departmentinput">
   <div class="entry" onchange="previous_values()">Telephone Number</div>
   <input type="text" name="telephone" id="subcatagoryinput">
   <div id="readwrite_buttons" class="hide">
    <button id="ok" onclick="document.forms[0].submit();return false;">OK</button>
    <button id="cancel" onclick="javascript:window.close();return false;">Cancel</button>
   </div>
   <div id="readonly_buttons" class="hide">
    <button id="back" onclick="javascript:window.close();return false;">Back</button>
   </div>
  </form>
 </body>
```

Comment: Thank you jeff for the input